# Required Field Validator only working in IE - not in chrome or firefox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, webforms

In my asp.net (vb on server side) application I am using a required field validator when a submit button is hit. The validator checks the value of `txtLatestEnd` - which is a hidden text box. The value of this text box is changed via javascript when the user selects an item on the screen before hitting submit.

I have noticed that the required field validator is only working in IE, but not chrome or firefox. Could anyone see why this is happening?

**Required field validator**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqLinks" Runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLatestEnd" Display="Dynamic"
EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="Links are required" CssClass="detailrow" Font-Bold="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Edit**

If it helps - here is the function on the server side that handles the button click

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    UpdateDatabase()
End Sub
```

and here is the button itself.

```
<asp:Button Runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save Milestone" CssClass="smalltextbutton" CausesValidation="True"></asp:Button>
```

Both the validator and button are their own table rows in an asp.net table

**Edit 2:** as requested, here's the code for the "hidden" field - by hidden, it is inside a div that is not displayed

```
<div id="divHiddenFields" style="DISPLAY:none">
    ---------------Hidden Fields---------------------------------------------------<br>
    Latest end date:<input type="text" ID="txtLatestEnd" Runat="server"><br>
    IDs &amp; Cats<input type="text" style="WIDTH:50%" runat="server" id="IDCATList"><br>
    creator: <input type="text" runat="server" id="hdnCreator"><br>
    county county<input type="text" runat="server" id="hdnLinkCount" value="0"><br>
    preloadDateArray<input type="text" runat="server" id="hdnPreLoadDates">
</div>
```

I have also tried moving the button and validator outside of the table, this does nothing to make the validator work.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: No errors showing in console. - if it helps. When the submit button is hit, its not handled by javascript but from the serverside - editing first post

Comment: JavaScript isn't disabled in your other browsers is it?

Comment: javascript is not disabled in any browser ive used to test this. Could it be that the validator is inside an asp.net table? I'm not sure why this would matter, but its the only thing I could think of

Comment: Perhaps its due to the "hidden field" (which would be set as display:none) which FF & chrome might not like. Could you change it from Hidden to Text - see if that makes a difference to isolate whether it is simply because its a hidden field. If it is then at least you have a more specific problem to work at/update the post about and we can go from there.

Comment: edited first post to show what the hidden field really is

Comment: Does `DOCTYPE` of your page affects on how tags are rendered? The only thing I can see is if you have `DOCTYPE XHTML` then you have to close "void tags".

Comment: doctype is HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN